# Microsoft Azure Functions - Setting up HttpTrigger / Binding to Table Storage for input - C#

Tags: c#, azure, http

I'm attempting to developer an Azure Function App which is triggered by a Http Request and takes the information on said request and added it into a Table in Table Storage. I developed in the portal and have been trying to redo the whole thing locally and publish it to Azure but running into issues with triggering the function and actually having it add to the Table I want it to add too... any help would be really appreciated!

This is what I have so far:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;

namespace LookUpService
{
    public static class AddConnectionDetails
    {
        [FunctionName("AddConnectionDetails")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ICollector<SocietyConnection> lookupTable)
        {
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

            lookupTable.Add(new SocietyConnection()
            {
                PartitionKey = data.PartitionKey,
                RowKey = data.RowKey,
                Connection = data.Connection,
                Organisation = data.Organisation
            });

            return new OkObjectResult($"{data.Organisation}({data.PartitionKey}) {data.RowKey} added to LookUp Table Storage");
        }

        public class SocietyConnection
        {
            public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
            public string RowKey { get; set; }
            public string Connection { get; set; }
            public string Organisation { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that theres no actual trigger on the function when i've published it and it isnt connecting to the table I want to put stuff into...

Let me know if I've not made anything clear enough!

Comment: try doing it in small steps. First add the http trigger and see if it works. Then, add the payload you need and check if you can read it. And finally add the table binding.

Comment: Cheers @ThiagoCustodio - i've tried to add the http trigger above. in terms of adding the payload and table binding - am i correct in trying to do this in the code and not in the portal after publishing?

Comment: yes, you need to do your tests before publishing

Answer (score 0):

First, if you develop code on local, you should bebug first. if the function works fine, then publish this function app to azure.

For your requirement, please use below code, it works fine on my side:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace FunctionApp49
{
    public class LogEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public string OriginalName { get; set; }
    }
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]

        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Table("AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon")] CloudTable cloudTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            TableQuery<LogEntity> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<LogEntity>().Where(
                TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal,
                        "FD2"),
                    TableOperators.And,
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThan,
                        "t")));

            // Execute the query and loop through the results
            foreach (LogEntity entity in
                await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(rangeQuery, null))
            {
                log.LogInformation(
                    $"{entity.PartitionKey}\t{entity.RowKey}\t{entity.Timestamp}\t{entity.OriginalName}");
            }

            return new OkObjectResult("111111111111111111");
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look of this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table?tabs=csharp#cloudtable